django string interpolation struggles
Hi so I am having a problem trying to concatenate in django. I have created a new templatetag and im trying to get the string interpolation right and im struggling a bit.
{% button text="Reset" onclick="test('{{user.id}}')" colour="yellow" %}
 
function test(user_id){
    console.log('user id:', user_id)
}

the console log just gives back user id: {{user.id}}
{% button text="Reset" onclick="test('"|add:user.id|stringformat:"s"|add:"')" colour="yellow" %}

I have also tried this way but it just gives me a syntax error.
any help on how to properly do this or even if its not possible any help would be great.
(still new to django)

Why do you even create buttons using a template tag? Just write its HTML directly rather than making it more complicated like this?

@AbdulAzizBarkat I want to create a reusable button component so I thought this might be a good idea to go ahead with
